# How to make a TextView have a fully round background, no matter the length of text

Tags: java, android, layout, textview

I am trying to make a notification count indicator, where a `TextView` would be showing the number of notifications present. The TextView would be placed on top of an `ImageView` that has a bell icon. The problem is, when I set the background of the TextView using a drawable resource, I get a round shape for numbers with lesser digits, say 1. But when larger numbers are being displayed in the TextView it won't have a round shape anymore. How would I make the TextView have a round-shaped with a colored background, no matter the text and its length?

When it displays the number "1", it is almost round.

[image: Notification icon for 1]

But when I put the number "99", it has rounded edges only. It's not fully round.

[image: Notification icon for 99]

This is my code for the drawable resource I used for the TextView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <solid android:color="#FF173C" />

    <size android:height="10dp" android:width="10dp"/>
    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="2000dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="2000dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="2000dp"
        android:topRightRadius="2000dp" />

    <padding android:right="5dp" android:left="5dp"/>

</shape>
```

Then I used it in TextView like this:

```
  <TextView
     android:id="@+id/notification_count"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="1"
     android:background="@drawable/bg_notification"
     android:textColor="@android:color/white"
     app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
     app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Comment: Can you include some code and screenshots?

Answer (score 6):

You can wrap_content of the `TextView` width and constraint the height so that it can equal to the width using `app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio = "1"`

But an issue will come up when the text is short (1 character), as the width now will be short; so a part of the text will be hidden, you can fix this by constraining a min width/height using `app:layout_constraintWidth_min` & `app:layout_constraintHeight_min` respectively.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/notification_count"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_notification"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:text="3"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_min="40dp"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_min="40dp"
    app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"  />
```

Preview:

[image]

Comment: the extra attributes were just what  I needed. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can add padding to your TextView itself so that the text doesn't distort the overall view.

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/notification_count"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="181"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_notification"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:padding="8dp" />
```

Change your shape XML to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">

    <size
        android:width="32dp"
        android:height="32dp" />

    <solid android:color="#FF173C" />

</shape>
```

That should work!

Comment: Have you tried removing the padding and size from your shape? And also using a larger padding value for your TextView?

Comment: Yes, I have tried it. If it works well for a one-digit number. It won't work well for two or three-digit numbers.

Comment: I updated my answer, I have tried it on a sample project and it seems to work just fine till 3 digit values, beyond which it looks a bit like an oval rather than a circle. If your values aren't going to be that high, you can use them, otherwise, you should be able to tweak a bit from this point. Try it once!

Comment: You can also increase vertical padding a bit higher than a horizontal one, dynamically, to compensate for larger values (which will bi horizontally wide, and that's what distorting the shape).

Comment: I tried the updated code. It works fine. Thanks

Comment: That's great. If it works for you and you found the efforts helpful, you can accept the answer. That will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Badges are usually not more than 99 and many large apps do the same, so try to size them manually.

```
<TextView
 ...
 android:layout_width="35dp"
 android:layout_height="35dp"
 android:text="99"
 ...
  />
```